# Northern Lights in Alaska

Tags: tours, winter, auroras, alaska

My wife and I would love to see the northern lights in Alaska this winter, but it can be difficult finding tour companies specializing in this sort of Alaska trip (almost all of them are for summer time trips to Alaska).
Is there a good reference site or tour company for this sort of trip to Alaska?

Comment: Have you tried searching for: Northern Lights tours Alaska? I just googled and quite a few come up...? Do you have restrictions, is it just the two of you, are you on a budget..?